# How do I successfully close the While loop in this code? It seems to not recognize my break condition?

Tags: python

The prompt for the problem goes as follows:

> Create an interactive student records system.
> Prompt the user for a student name.
> Then prompt the user for a numeric grade
> Repeat this until the user enters 'done' in place of a name.
> Then print each student and the average of their grades

I have come up with the following code (I'm a beginner guys, sorry if this is obvious)

```
# I am creating a dictionary so I can store multiple values that are associated with one name
lst = []
dict = {}

while True:
  try:
    name = str(input("Please enter student's name."))
    grade = int(input("Please enter grade student recieved."))
    
    if (name not in list(dict.keys()) and name != "done"):
      lsst = []
      lsst.append(grade)
      dict[name] = lsst
      print(lsst)
      continue

      
    
    elif name in list(dict.keys()):
      lsst.append(grade)
      print(lsst)
      continue
    
    elif name == "done":
      break
  
  except ValueError:
    print("Try Again")
    pass

for i in range(list(dict.keys())):
  print(f"{name}: {grade}")
```

I am trying to print the averages after I type 'done' for the name input, but it just moves on to the next input inquiry. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The `break` just breaks the `try`-block, the programm then continues the `while`-loop. Move the except-block directly below the try-block, then dedent the if-elif-elif block so it gets outside the try-except block. BTW, python indentation standard is 4 spaces per level, see [PEP8 - Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: There are a few issues with the code you provide. The most obvious problem is that it does not run correctly (this line throws error `for i in range(list(dict.keys())):`). Please fix your code and make sure it runs correctly and behaves exactly how you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistakes in the code but I will break them down in my corrected version.

```
names_and_grades = {} # I renamed this variable because there is a built in type called dict in Python.

while True: # Using while True is usually discouraged but in this case, it's hard to avoid that.
    try:
        name = input("Please enter student's name.") # No need to convert to string as it takes the input as a string by default.

        if name == "done": # After you prompted for a name immediately check whether the user entered done. This way, you can break right after that.
            break

        grade = int(input("Please enter grade student recieved."))

        if name not in names_and_grades.keys():
            names_and_grades[name] = [grade] # We don't actually need a separate list as the entry in the dictionary will be the list itself (that's why it's put between brackets).
        elif name in names_and_grades.keys():
            names_and_grades[name].append(grade) # Once the list was declared, you can simply append it.

        print(names_and_grades[name]) # No need to repeat this twice in the if-else statements, you can just write it after them. And a very important thing, there is no need to use continue, since you are using if-elfe. When you are using if-else, only one of the blocks will be used, the first block where the condition evaluates as true.

    except ValueError:
        print("Try Again")

for k in names_and_grades.keys():
    print(f"{k}: {names_and_grades[k]}") # This is the simplest way to iterate through a dictionary (if you want to format the entries), by iterating through the keys of the dictionary and with the help of the keys, calling the appropriate values.
```

I hope this helps, let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: 1) `str(input(...` works, but `input()` returns a string already - no need to convert to string. 2) no need to check for `name != "done` a second time, there's a `break` on that condition a few lines above

Comment: This was excellent! Thank you so much for breaking down my errors and helping me to make my code more clear. That was so so so helpful!

Comment: Thank you @ack, I accidentally left it as it was in the original code, now I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@I8ACooky - there are some logic and syntax errors, so I will suggest you to run this and see if you can get some ideas to work out your own later:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


grades = defaultdict(list)   # in case for multiple scores for a student
print('Welcome to the simple Scoring program. ')

while True:
    
    try:
        
        name = input("Please enter student's name.")
        score = int(input("Please enter grade student recieved: "))

        if name == 'done' and score == 0:
            break
        
        grades[name].append(score)

    except ValueError:
        print('Try Again....?')
      
print(dict(grades))

#------------------------
# average scores leave as an exercise...
```

Outputs:

```py
Welcome to the simple Scoring program. 
Please enter student's name.Adam
Please enter grade student recieved: 100
Please enter student's name.Bob
Please enter grade student recieved: 60
Please enter student's name.Cindy
Please enter grade student recieved: 80
Please enter student's name.Adam
Please enter grade student recieved: 80
Please enter student's name.Bob
Please enter grade student recieved: 100
Please enter student's name.Cindy
Please enter grade student recieved: 90
Please enter student's name.done
Please enter grade student recieved: 0
{'Adam': [100, 80], 'Bob': [60, 100], 'Cindy': [80, 90]}
```

Comment: `done` shouldn't be assumed a valid student's name.

Comment: It just follows the original PO as a way to signal `done`. It certainly can be and should be improved --- for the author to work on. Right?

Comment: OP tried to break immediately after inputting `done` - have a close look. Asking for a grade for `done` makes no sense.

Comment: Good note - the PO should make a note and fix in later work.  We just provide some 'ideas` for him to work on... (not the final solution~)